# Using "plot for" in gnuplot to vary parameters

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I want to use the `plot for` feature in gnuplot to plot functions with varying parameters. Here an example

```
par = "1 2" #two values for the parameter
f(x,a) = sin(a*x)
g(x,a) = cos(a*x)
plot for [i=1:words(par)]  g(x, word(par,i)), f(x, word(par,i))
```

What I expect is the plotting of the four functions `g(x,1)`, `g(x,2`, `f(x,1)`, and `f(x,2)`.

But for whatever reason only three functions are plotted, namely: `g(x,1)`, `g(x,2`, and `f(x,2)`.

This seems completely arbitrary to me.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to repeat the `for` condition:

```
plot for [i=1:words(par)]  g(x, word(par,i)), for [i=1:words(par)] f(x, word(par,i))
```