# Iterative parametric plot with gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I want to use the iterative plot function `plot for` in gnuplot for a parametric plot.

```
set parametric
f(x) = x
plot for [i=1:2] t,f(i*t)
```

However, as I learned [in this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37005010/using-plot-for-in-gnuplot-to-vary-parameters/37005781#37005781), the `for` iteration ends after a comma. So the iteration only applies to `t` and not to `f(i*t)`. But since a parametric plot needs a pair of functions separated by a comma, how can I tell gnuplot to iteratively plot my parametric plot?

Comment: I don't know, but here on `Version 5.0 patchlevel 3` it seems to work

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work in gnuplot 4.6

Answer (score 2):

Did you actually try it? `gnuplot` distinguishes a comma between parametric coordinates and the end of a `plot-element` as it is called (which can contain a `for`-loop): this is simply done by counting the number of coordinates given.

E.g.,

```
set parametric
set size ratio -1
plot for [i=1:3] cos(t),i*sin(t) title "Ellipse ".i, \
     for [i=1:3] i*cos(t),i*sin(t) title "Circle ".i
```

If you do

```
plot for [i=1:3] cos(t),i*sin(t),i*cos(t),i*sin(t)
```

then you keep the 3 ellipses (well, including the circle when i=1), and have one circle plotted for `i=3` (the value `i` kept after the `for` loop) from the last pair of coordinates.

Comment: Which gnuplot version do you use? I have gnuplot 4.6, and it seems not to work there.

Comment: I have gnuplot 5, but this also works with version 4.6 (patchlevel 6), it should work with versions >= 4.4. Please give detail on what "seems not to work". You should obtain 6 ellipses/circle in the first case (with ellipse 1 and circle 1 identical), 3 ellipses (1 being a circle) and 1 large circle (radius 3) in the second case.